# Labelling an arbitrary shape in Java2D

Tags: java, java-2d

I am developing a kind of chart with shapes in Java2D. I want to label these shapes by writing some text over them at the midpoint.

For the most part, just getting the center of the rectangular bounds suffices. This is the fairly straight forward code I use.

```
Area area = segment.area;

int topLeftX = (int)area.getBounds().getX();
int topLeftY = (int)area.getBounds().getY();

double width = (int)area.getBounds().getWidth();
double height = (int)area.getBounds().getHeight();

double xPoint = topLeftX + (width/2);
double yPoint = topLeftY + (height/2);


g2d.drawString(segment.name, (int)xPoint, (int)yPoint);
```

However some of the shapes I have, are kind of arc shaped (ie. hollowed out), so that the center point actually ends up being in some other shape.

I am trying to find some way of finding a point in a shape where I can place my text, so that it represents the actual shape, not some shape that might be "inside".

any thoughts ideas?

Comment: If you arc is not too curved, you can try to draw a line that joins the 2 extremities and the draw the isoscele triangle whose 3rd corner touches the arc. Then you can put your label along one of the 2 equal length sides (maybe choose the more horizontal one for easier reading)

Comment: workaround-idea: use different colors for the shapes, and then the labels can have the same colors and they can be outside the shape... Or you could post it at http://math.stackexchange.com because this is not really a programming question